# s3 compare keys with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, key

I have 2 buckets contains the following files:

```
freedom-meital3
\text4
\text5   
freedom-meital2
\text5
\text4
```

I want to compare the etag only when the key is the same. i am getting wrong syntax. the problem is with: `if key['Key'] == key2['Key']`

```
 conn = client('s3')  # again assumes boto.cfg setup, assume AWS S3
    for key2 in conn.list_objects(Bucket='freedom-meital3')['Contents']:
        for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='freedom-meital2')['Contents']:
            print(key2['Key'])
            print(key['Key'])
            if key['Key'] == key2['Key']
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to find files with the same key *and* the same eTag, or the same key and *different* eTags? What are you going to do with them once found?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want want to do when the `if` statement evaluates as true? That isn't being handled, you are missing a `:` after it as well. Maybe something like:

```
 conn = client('s3')  # again assumes boto.cfg setup, assume AWS S3
    for key2 in conn.list_objects(Bucket='freedom-meital3')['Contents']:
        for key in conn.list_objects(Bucket='freedom-meital2')['Contents']:
            if key['Key'] == key2['Key']:
                print(key2['Key'])
                print(key['Key'])
```